# EnrichMediator: Cannot add child, since the target is not a JSON array

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a request payload like this.

```
{"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]}}
```

And I capture it in a property.

```
<property expression="json-eval($.reservationBody)" name="reservationBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="json-eval($)" name="reserveration-before" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

After this, I have a different request that looks like this:

```
{"roomStays":[{"arrivalDate":"2020-07-20","departureDate":"2020-07-21","numAdults":1}]}
```

I capture that info in "roomInfo" and try to append this to the original "reservationsBody" JSON using Enrich.

```
<property expression="json-eval($)" name="roomInfo" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
     <format>$1</format>
     <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('reserveration-before')"/>
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <enrich>
     <source clone="true" property="roomInfo" type="property"/>
     <target action="child" property="reservationBody" type="property"/>
  </enrich>
```

I put logging before the Enrich tags and the JSONs I've created all look fine, but once I try to enrich the original JSON, I get

```
ERROR - EnrichMediator Cannot add child, since the target {"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]}} is not an JSON array
```

I am confused because it definitely looks like a JSON array? Sorry if the fix is obvious, I am very new to WSO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question the following is not a JSON array. Therefore to overcome your issue you have two options.

```
{"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]}}
```

**Option 1**

You can convert the above to a JSON array as follows before storing it in the property mediator. You can do this with a number of options such as using payload factory mediator, enrich mediator, property mediator, etc.

```
[{"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]}}]
```

But then the generated response would be as follows.

```
[{"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]}},{"roomStays":[{"arrivalDate":"2020-07-20","departureDate":"2020-07-21","numAdults":1}]}]
```

**Option 2**

The above exception occurs when the target that you want to enrich is a property (Refer to the java code in [1]). When the target is a property it checks if the target property contains a JSON array and if not throws the error [2].

Therefore in order to avoid this, you can follow a bit different approach to enrich the payload.

Capture the payloads in properties

```
<property expression="json-eval($.reservationBody)" name="reservationBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property expression="json-eval($)" name="roomInfo" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Enrich the message context with the first payload (reservationBody)

```
 <enrich>
    <source clone="true" property="reservationBody" type="property"/>
    <target type="body"/>
 </enrich>
```

Then enrich the message body with the roomInfo property as a child element

```
<enrich>
            <source clone="true" property="roomInfo" type="property"/>
            <target action="child" xpath="json-eval($)"/>
</enrich>
```

Then the generated output will look like following

```
{"guest":{"name":{"firstName":"MARK","lastName":"DAVIS","middleInit":"G","title":"MR"},"addresses":[{"addressLine1":"4148 PINE HILL CV N","addressType":"home","city":"LAKELAND","country":"US","postalCode":"38002","state":"XX"},{"addressLine1":"522 South Road","addressType":"business","city":"Ploughkeepsie","company":"I B M","country":"US","postalCode":"12601","state":"NY"}],"emails":[{"emailAddress":"tom.smith@yahoo.com","emailType":"home"},{"emailAddress":"Tom@IBM.COM","emailType":"business"}],"phones":[{"phoneNumber":"0019013774041","phoneType":"home"},{"phoneNumber":"496196939781","phoneType":"business"}]},"roomStays":[{"arrivalDate":"2020-07-20","departureDate":"2020-07-21","numAdults":1}]}
```

Therefore depending on the output, you expect you can either follow option 1 or the option 2

[1]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/elementary/Target.java#L437

[2]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/elementary/Target.java#L441